# Migrate data from on-premise to Azure SQL VM

Tags: azure

We have SQL database running on-premise, we need to migrate some of the tables to Azure (not the whole database) and perhaps also need to do some transformation during the migration.

Came across this Azure Database Migration Service but seems like this service can only migrate the database as a whole?

We need a tool that allows us to have more control, much like a SSIS package. Can anyone advise is this available on Azure?

Searched internet for some time but unable to find any answer yet.

Comment: You can use ADF or azure synapse analytics pipeline

Answer (score 0):

That the Azure Database Migration Service (DMS) typically focuses on transferring whole databases rather than particular tables or subsets of data is true, as you correctly pointed out.

**To transform and move data from On-premises SQL to azure you can use [Azure data factory.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction)**

> Azure Data Factory enables you to move and transform data from various sources to various destinations. It's a managed cloud service designed specifically for handling complex hybrid extract-transform-load (ETL), extract-load-transform (ELT), and data integration projects.

***With below steps you can transform and move data from On-premises SQL to azure using ADF:***

- In your Azure subscription, **create an Azure Data Factory** instance.
- **Make a pipeline in Azure Data Factory**.
- **Connect to your on-premises SQL database using a source dataset,** and then indicate the table(s) you wish to move.
- **Use data transformation techniques** like data mapping, filtering, or aggregation to carry out any necessary transformations.
- **Set up a sink dataset to connect your desired Azure SQL Database**.
- To start the migration process, **run the pipeline.**

Comment: Hi Pratik, I am checking the ADF now, I can see that it's certified for many ISO and so on, however my question is, can this ADF be used to transfer payment related data? Is this PCI compliant? Thank you for your advice again.

Comment: PCI compliance is not something that comes naturally to Azure Data Factory. A variety of services, such as Azure Data Factory, are offered by Azure as a cloud platform, though, and they can be utilised to create PCI-compliant solutions. Achieving PCI compliance requires a number of things, including the planning and execution of the overall architecture, security precautions, and adherence to PCI DSS (Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard) criteria.